# How to add data in my table view like this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uicollectionviewcell

Like this need to show in my table view.How can i insert data into the row.
[image]

Comment: Anything you have tried so far? Any research? Or, do you want to hire somebody to accomplish your task?

Comment: use expand and collapse table view for this

Comment: s tried....if u give some idea means i will implement in my task #fahri

Comment: ok Anbu karthik bro i will try that..

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create 2 tables:

- **CarCategory** has columns: CarCategoryId, Name.
- **Car** has columns: CarId, Name, and relationship with **CarCategory** table.

Hope this could help.

Comment: Probably a bit more explanation would help OP understanding your answer.